# Power Bi Replicating an IF Statement by using SWITCH () TRUE

Tags: switch-statement, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I tried to replicate this excel formula logic, into DAX:

```
Total Price= IF(U =" "," ",IF(Unit="N"," ",
IF(Unit="OTHER", Cost * U,
IF(AND(OR(Unit="E",Unit="C"),Currency="EUR"), Cost * (value of Exchange Rate, when Currency equals "EUR" ) * U,
IF(AND(OR(Unit="E",Unit="C"),Currency="JPY"),(Cost/(value of Exchange Rate, when Currency equals "Yen"))* U,
IF(Unit="N",Cost * Price, Cost * U))))))
```

Any idea on how can I start?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but you're on the ringt track (imho) using SWITCH().
Do you want to create a measure or a calculated column? Also some sample of what you've tried and example data also helps.